# Access - track changing code only works when i press shift while opening database

Tags: vba, ms-access, changelog

I made a database for users to plan work. After i process the record, i use a checkbox to mark it as "entered".
I adapted some code i found on the interwebs to track changes that users make (only after i marked it) so that I know if i have to edit something.

This works fine, **but only when i press shift while opening the DB?!**

I use the "Form_BeforeUpdate()" and "Form_AfterUpdate()" event to execute an SQL to grab the correct line and afterwards compare them. When i don't press "shift" while opening the DB, there is no difference between 'before' and 'after' (both are the 'before' value??)

So in short: on the BeforeEvent the record is stored in the temp table. On the AfterEvent the record is stored in another temp table.
Those two are compared and the different field stored in a recordset (together with the username, date,...) and written to the ChangeLog-table.
Works like a charm. But only when i press shift on opening the DB...

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
            Dim sSQL    As String
            Dim sUN     As String     'UserName
    bWasNewRec = Me.NewRecord
    sUN = Environ("UserName")
    
    If Me.Ingevoerd = True Then    '"me.ingevoerd is the checkbox
        'Empty TEMP-table          'temp-tables are the 2 tables to store the event values
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM temp_BeforeUpdate;"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM temp_AfterUpdate;"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
        'Copy BeforeUpdate values to TEMP-table
        If Not bWasNewRec Then
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO temp_beforeupdate (changedType, changedDate, changedUser, tbl_ID) " & _
                   "SELECT 'OldVal' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, '" & sUN & "' AS Expr3, " & Me.planningID & " as Expr4, * FROM tbl_Planning WHERE planningID = " & Me.planningID & ";"
            CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
        Dim recBefUp    As DAO.Recordset
        Dim recAftUp    As DAO.Recordset
        Dim recEdited   As DAO.Recordset
        Dim sSQL        As String
        Dim sUN         As String
        Dim fld         As Integer
    
    sUN = Environ("UserName")
    If ((Me.Ingevoerd = True) And (Not bWasNewRec)) Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO temp_AfterUpdate ( changedType, changedDate, changedUser, tbl_ID ) " & _
               "SELECT 'NewVal' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, '" & sUN & "' AS Expr3, " & Me.planningID & " as Expr4, * FROM tbl_Planning WHERE planningID = " & Me.planningID & ";"
        
        CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
        Set recBefUp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 temp_BeforeUpdate.* FROM temp_BeforeUpdate WHERE (temp_BeforeUpdate.changedType = 'OldVal') ORDER BY temp_BeforeUpdate.changedDate DESC;")             'RecordBeforeUpdate = SQL voor update
        Set recAftUp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 temp_AfterUpdate.*  FROM temp_AfterUpdate  WHERE (temp_AfterUpdate.changedType = 'NewVal')  ORDER BY temp_AfterUpdate.changedDate DESC;")               'RecordAfterUpdate = SQL na update
        
        'enter in "ChangeLog":
            'Set recEdited = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ChangeLog")                                            'ChangeLog is where i check if something was changed
            Set recEdited = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ChangeLog")                              'Recordset to store the before- and after values
            For fld = 9 To recBefUp.Fields.Count - 1
                If Not (Nz(recBefUp.Fields(fld).Value, 0) = Nz(recAftUp.Fields(fld).Value, 0)) Then
                    recEdited.AddNew
                        recEdited.Fields(2).Value = recBefUp.Fields(2).Value                                'ChangedDate
                        recEdited.Fields(3).Value = recBefUp.Fields(3).Value                                'ChangedUser
                        recEdited.Fields(4).Value = "tbl_Planning"                                          'Formulier
                        recEdited.Fields(5).Value = recBefUp.Fields(8).Value                                'TOS
                        recEdited.Fields(6).Value = recBefUp.Fields(9).Value                                'Startdatum
                        recEdited.Fields(7).Value = recBefUp.Fields(5).Value                                'planningID
                        recEdited.Fields(8).Value = recBefUp.Fields(4).Value                                'ID-nummer
                        recEdited.Fields(9).Value = recBefUp.Fields(fld).Name                               'Veld
                        recEdited.Fields(10).Value = Nz(recBefUp.Fields(fld).Value, "-")                    'Oude waarde
                        recEdited.Fields(11).Value = Nz(recAftUp.Fields(fld).Value, "-")                    'Nieuwe waarde
                    recEdited.Update
                End If
            Next fld
        'Empty the temp table.
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM temp_BeforeUpdate;"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM temp_AfterUpdate;"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
        Set recBefUp = Nothing
        Set recAftUp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

'''
```

Comment: No idea why shift key would make a difference with this process. Is there some code that executes when db is opened without shift key bypass? Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppAuditCode.html

Comment: I used AllenBowne's as a basis for my code. You were right: the form that opened as default had some code that is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I incorperated some code to make a stable connection with the BackEnd (tables). For some reason this messed up the AfterEvent. When i disable the next section, it works again...

```
Public dbConn As DAO.Database
    Private Sub Form_Close()
        Set dbConn = Nothing
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
        Set dbConn = OpenDatabase("X:\Arr22_TABLES.accdb")
    End Sub
```